# why does this code display the date being SAT where with NSDateComponent setWeekday I used 1 for SUN?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdatecomponent

Why does this code display the date being SAT where with NSDateComponent & setWeekday I used 1 for SUN?

```
// Set Day
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setWeekday:1];
[comps setHour:13];
[comps setMinute:30];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *tempDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

NSDateFormatter *format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE HH:mm"];    
NSString *s = [format stringFromDate:tempDate];
NSLog(@"Finishing : %@", s);

// Gave => 2011-04-05 09:50:28.467 test1[39840:207] Finishing : Sat 13:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting an NSDateComponents with only the weekday, hour, and minute set apparently gives you a date in the year 1. As this is long before the Julian/Gregorian calendar transition, you will end up with odd results in some places where some methods interpret the date in the proleptic Gregorian calendar while others interpret it in the Julian calendar.

When I try your code with a more detailed date format, I get `Sat 0001-01-01 13:30:00 -045602`. Try it after using `setYear:` on the components and you'll get sensible results.